# Creating constants for apple watch and iphone application?

Tags: ios, constants, apple-watch

How can we create constants usable for both Apple watch and iPhone applications?

Comment: Are you using `.m` for your constants?

Comment: i am using .h files for iPhone app

Comment: Then you should be able to use that, can't you? What error you get..

Comment: i cannot import .h files

Answer (score 1):

Apple Watch Extension and iPhone Application reside in two completely different sandboxes. They normally do not share data unless you set up [App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW4).

To share code, you have to compile your code into framework. In your case, you will have to create a framework that contains your `.h` constant file and link the framework to both iPhone app and WatchKit Extension.

See [Framework tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)

See "*Communicating with iPhone*" on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/) by Apple for more detail